# Can I share my Internet from my laptop by bluetooth?

Tags: windows, bluetooth, internet-connection, internet-sharing

I want to share the Internet connection from my Windows 7 PC using Bluetooth so my other devices can connect to the Internet through my computer. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: try to use LAN for Internet Connection Sharing.

Comment: Windows 10 has made this feature easier to use. Go to `Settings`>`Network & Internet`>`Mobile Hotspot` to enable.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about connecting things like cell phones to a Windows 7 system (e.g. older Windows Mobile phones), most of these can only use the Bluetooth "Dial Up Networking" (DUN) profile.  IIRC this is basically PPP over a Bluetooth virtual serial port.  This is not "PAN" or "Personal Area Networking."

I had luck sharing Internet access between a desktop and laptop using the WIDCOMM software.  This was through PAN and not DUN, though.  From what I remember it had options to create a network adapter that accepted incoming Bluetooth DUN connections.  I don't believe it is possible through the built-in Microsoft Bluetooth support.

Answer (score 1):

[Another article](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/share-internet-bluetooth-58494.html) (and [another one](http://www.geekzone.co.nz/content.asp?contentid=445)) deal with connection sharing in general. The idea is:

- on the "host" computer (the one connected to the Internet), activate connection sharing on the network connection connected to the Internet
- pair to your other "client" computer via bluetooth
- on the "client" computer, activate the Bluetooth network connection

On that last step (when I use my phone as the "host" computer), you might have to right-click the "host" computer icon on your "client" computer's "Printer and devices", then select "`Connect using > Direct connection`"*

*: free translation from my OS language

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://www.geekzone.co.nz/content.asp?contentid=445) should help, but you might have to guess a little on the devices that are connecting to it because it's written for Windows Mobile (though the Windows portion of it should be pretty similar in Windows 7)